# what's the order surefire-plugin execute test case?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, surefire

> based on [Does Maven Surefire execute test cases sequentially by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268899/does-maven-surefire-execute-test-cases-sequentially-by-default), I know that the surefire execute test cases sequentially, in other words, One by One.

---

I want to know which test cases executed first and which next, Through output information of surefire, I find that the order maybe random, for example:

- test
- boyTest.java
- subdir

  - girlTest.java
- parentTest.java
  the test directory has three test case: and the testcase execute order is girlTest.java, parentTest.java,boyTest.java

> and So I want to make sure that ***whether the order that testCase executed is `random`***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify that the ordering surefire used is the one you expect, run your build with debug enabled (`-x` flag). E.g. in my case I see the following:

```
mvn clean install -X | grep runOrder
   ...
<runOrder default-value="filesystem">hourly</runOrder>
[DEBUG]   (s) runOrder = hourly
```

By default order is not random but defined through how the file system returns the list of the tests (`filesystem` in surefire terms).

There are other available orderings which you can choose through `surefire.runOrder` property (one of which is `random`).

For more information see [Surefire plugin runOrder](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder)